# Sending all website custom emails by mailchimp

Tags: email

I want all my emails which is going by my website like "Registration Email, Forget Password Email etc" will send through mailchimp. Anyone can suggest how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes, you should use transactional email API. Mailchimp company provides a service called [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) that implements it.